# R-shiny: group data in multiple columns based on checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r

I am trying to get for each id, the total number of records from date[1] to date [2] with test A/B/C.Then create a line plot (3 lines on the same plot). I have 3 choices in checkboxGroupInput as below. My data for A:C is in different columns. I am filtering my data based on user input but I am not sure how do I group it based on user choices of A/B/C to generate a lineplot with multiple lines

mydata

```
id date batch_a_1 batch_a_2 batch_b_1 batch_b_2 batch_c_2 
rec1 2022-01-01 1 0 1 0 1
rec2 2022-01-03 0 1 0 0 0
rec3 2022-01-01 1 0 1 0 0
rec1 2022-01-03 0 1 0 1 0
rec1 2022-01-01 1 0 1 0 0
rec2 2022-01-03 0 1 0 0 1
rec3 2022-01-01 1 0 1 0 0
rec3 2022-01-03 0 1 0 1 0

checkboxGroupInput(
                    inputId = "test",
                    choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
                    selected = c("A", "B", "C"),
                    label = "Select test type"
                  ),
```

This is what I tried but I am not sure how do i group the data (group_by(input$test))to generate a line plot for selected id and test (A/B/C)

```
mydata %>%
  filter(
    id == input$id,
    if_any(matches(str_c(
      'batch_', tolower(input$test)
    )), ~
      .x == 1),
    date >= input$Dates[1] &
      date <= input$Dates[2],
    
  )
```

Comment: there are no "A","B","C" in your id column...

provide a small reproducible example. Chances you'll get help will be much much better.

for example provide the code to make the dataset. 
provide the code of a ggplot that uses your data and an hardcoded id.

even without providing the shinyapp code. You can just test inputs with a list, like
input = list(id="A").

Comment: "A","B","C" is coming from the column names and below is how I am matching the choices. if_any(matches(str_c(
          'batch_', tolower(input$test)
        )), ~
          .x == 1)

Comment: give us a reproducible example of a plot that you want to make, outside of Shiny. Then you'll get help on how to make it work also with a shiny checkboxGroupInput

Comment: Pretty much what you are trying to do (use input to modify plot): https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html#example-ggplot2